# How to specify the order of evaluation in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm on `JSF-2.1_29`. As far as I can see, the order of manged bean's methodw invokation corresponds to how they are placed in the markup. In my particular case I have:

```
<h:outputText value="Rows count:"/>
<h:outputText value="#{bonusBean.rowsCount}"/>

<rich:dataTable id="bonusesTable"
                    var="bonus"
                    value="#{bonusBean.list}"
                    render="ds"
                    rowClasses="tr0, tr1">

    <!-- Columns, etc... -->
</rich:dataTable>
```

ManagedBean itself:

```
public class BonusBean{

private Integer rowsCount = 0;

//GET, SET

public List<BonusActionDTO> getList(){
    List<BonusActionDTO> lst = new ArrayList<BonusActionDTO>();

    //Getting the list from a persistance storage

    rowsCount = lst.size();
    return lst;
}
```

In that case `getRowsCount()` is being invoked first which returns 0, so the `Rows count: 0` is going to be printed when the page is loaded first, although the table may contain some rows. After invokation of `getRowsCount()` method, `getList()` is being invoked, so the actual `Rows count` is going to printed only after refreshing the page. How can I reorder that order of methods invokation? Is it possible in `JSF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can change the order of the getter invocations. But apart of this, the dependency of the result of a get method on the call of another get method is a bad design. Two getter should return the same results without regard of the order in which they are called.